# Autoconf on Windows

Tags: makefile, mingw, autoconf

I'm currently trying to compile Freeglut on Windows 7 using MinGW. The problem is that there is just a makefile.am and a makefile.in. Thanks to Google, I found out that these belong to autoconf. The problem is that I haven't found a autoconf.exe file, just files for MSYS or Cygwin.

Is there a way to get/compile a exe file? If there is, is it also available for x64 windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Makefile.am is the input to automake, and Makefile.in is a template that is turned into the actual Makefile.

If you install MSYS, then you can unpack the tarball, then run `./configure` and then `make` to build it.

But why would you do this when someone else has made [32- and 64-bit windows binaries already?](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/)